# Error for compiling

Tags: errors, compiling

[image]

Hello I have compiled several .tex file and get this error. What is that?

Comment: That error description is quite clear: You don't have `EB Garamond` available.

Comment: Perhaps the OP is working from a template, and has not encountered this situation before. That might happen if previous TeX usage always involved pdftex, or always involved an auto-installer such as MiKTeX. Possible solution: Open a Terminal, and type this: `tlmgr Install ebgaramond`

Comment: @RobtA That is unlikely to help. It might. But it is more likely that the font is installed for TeX but not the system, yet the code tries to load the font by name rather than path. Also, on any Unix-like platform, you'll need root privileges.

Comment: @cfr On my Ubuntu system, I have texlive 2016 installed (directly from TeXLive, not the Ubuntu package manager) in my home directory. So, no root privilege needed. Although fontspec can load fonts by font name (even with spaces), it may be the EB Garamond font must be called by file name or by `EB Garamond 12` instead.

Comment: @RobtA I don't need root privileges either, but most people do because most people install that way. (I don't install into my home directory, mind. I consider the stuff there more important than the system files, so I wouldn't gain much by protecting the system files alone.) `EB Garamond` works just fine provided the font is installed for the system e.g. `fontconfig` knows about it.

Comment: @RobtA I tried to use terminal as you said. "You don't have permission to change the installation in any way,
specifically, the directory /usr/local/texlive/2015/tlpkg/ is not writable.
Please run this program as administrator, or contact your local admin.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting."

Comment: Folks if this is interesting question please vote up me!

Comment: Then try Terminal: `sudo tlmgr Install ebgaramond` and provide password. Also might be necessary for package `ly1`. If that does not help, then the problem cannot be diagnosed from the limited information provided.